# React-native boolean=true only for concerned array and false for others, Flatlist

Tags: arrays, react-native, boolean, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to make sure that on press not all `this.state.users.expended=true` and only the one i've clicked on, the problem is that i am using flatlist and it is changing the state of all expanded in all array elements I've tried using loops, conditional statement and wrapping the array in another state but no result. can anyone help, thanks

here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image, ImageBackground, PixelRatio, Platform, UIManager, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'
import DropDownItem from 'react-native-drop-down-item';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={

    users : [
  {
    spec1: require("./Icons/Growth.png"),
    spec2:require("./Icons/RED.png"),
    spec3:require("./Icons/LAGG.png"),
    name: 'Induce',
    price: '$',
    image: require("./Icons/RF.jpg"),
    icon: '',
    category: 'NA',
    textLeft:'',
    expanded: false      
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false      
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false     
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false       
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false     
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false       
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    spec1: '5a31077f6dda99e234ad6727',
    name: 'Cathy Gilliam',
    price: 'EXOVENT',
    image: 'red',
    icon: '',
    expanded: false

  },

]

    }
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }

      }

      changeLayout = () => {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);

        this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
      }

       render() {


    return (

      <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor:'#262A2C',
        flex:1
      }}>
      <FlatList
     style={{marginTop:80,}}
        data={this.state.users}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <View>

          <ImageBackground

          source={item.image} 
        //pay FlatIcon or design personal one
          style={{ 

            resizeMode: 'contain',

          position:'relative',

          width: wp('100%'), 
          left: wp('0%'),
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: 'grey',
          padding: hp('6%'),
          }}
        >
       <View
            style={{
              flex:1,
             height:hp('19%'),
             width: wp('100%'),
             //height:hp('21%'),

              borderBottomColor: 'grey',

            }}>


               <Image
               style={{
               width:wp('10%'),
               height:hp('5%'),
               left:wp('-10%'),
               top:hp('-5.5%'),
               //tintColor:'#81F018'
               }}
               source={item.spec1}/>
              <Image
               style={{
               width:wp('10%'),
               height:hp('5.5%'),
               left:wp('-10%'),
               top:hp('0%'),
               //tintColor:'#81F018'
               }}
               source={item.spec2}/>

               <Image
               style={{
               width:wp('10%'),
               height:hp('5.5%'),
               left:wp('-10%'),
               top:hp('6%'),
               //tintColor:'#81F018'
               }}
               source={item.spec3}/>

              <Text 
              style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',
               fontSize: 22, 
               left:item.name.length<=5 ? wp('32.5%'):wp('27.5%'),
               top:hp('-9.5%'),

               //left:item.name.length<=5 ? wp('31.5%'):wp('26.5%'),
               //top:hp('-1.5%')
              //left:item.name.length<=5 ? wp('32.5%'):wp('27.5%'),
               //top:hp('-3.5%')
               }}>
               {item.name}
               </Text>
              <Text
              style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 25, 
                top: hp('-25%'),
                left:wp('80%')
                // top: hp('-14%'),
                //left:wp('80%')
                //top: hp('-19%'),
                //left:wp('80%')
              }}>
              {item.price} 
              </Text>


          </View>





   </ImageBackground>
   <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={this.changeLayout} style={{ padding: 10,

    backgroundColor:'black',

    left:wp('-10.9%'),
    top:hp('0%'),
    width: wp('120%'),
    height:hp('5%')}}>

</TouchableOpacity>
<View style={{ height: this.state.expanded ? null : 0, overflow: 'hidden', backgroundColor:'black' }}>
            <Text style={{
               fontSize: 17,
    color: 'white',
    padding: 10}}>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
              Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
              when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
              It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
              remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
              containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
              like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </Text>
          </View>  
    </View>
        )}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get `index` of the item to update:

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
```

Pass it to `changeLayout` to update the item:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeLayout(index)}
```

Then, use it on `changeLayout`:

```
changeLayout = index => {
  LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);

  this.setState(({ users }) => ({
    users: users.map((u, i) => ({ ...u, expanded: i === index }))
  }));
};
```

Finally, use it:

```
<View style={{ height: item.expanded ? null : 0, ...
```

Comment: Hey i have tried your suggestion but it isn't expanded when clicking on the View. Is it possible to have a Snack example, maybe I am missing something

Comment: Hey I am actually working on your code, It is working but the functionality to close the view has been removed I tried replacing expanded: true with expanded:!this.state.users but no result, I tried to also create another method to close it but still not working. In short how to re-enable the closing while clicking again on the view and still using your proposition to make it work. thanks

Comment: I found a way but it requires to click, one that closes the other that opens the new view. Just finding out a one time click for the full function

Answer (score 0):

You can keep expanded state separate from array of data state something like `expandedUserId`. This makes it easy to update and also does not update the flat list data. You need to pass `expandedUserId` inside `extraData` prop of FlatList so that flat list also updates when this state updates.

A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements PureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

And inside you renderItem function you can simply check if expandedUserId is equals to id of current row.

```
const expanded = this.state.expandedUserId = data.item.id;
```

If your app enables multiple user to be expanded at a time you can make `expandedUserId` state an object like

```
expandedUserId: { '12': true, '25': false, '37': true }
```